# Loop through Dictionary with string key=>vals?? C#

Tags: c#

```
public static string DictToQueryString(Dictionary<string, string> data)
{
    string querystring = "";

    foreach (string key, string val in data)
         querystring += key + "=" + val + "&";

    return querystring;
}
```

How i foreach?

Comment: Coming from a PHP background, I take it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "code" would have an extraneous `"&"` on the end. Do you want this? It's likely that you don't want this but please correct if you do. Assuming not, the simplest approach is to let [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) do its job:

```
public static string DictToQueryString(Dictionary<string, string> data) { 
    return String.Join(
        "&",
        data.Select(kvp => String.Format("{0}={1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value))
            .ToArray()
    );
```

In C# 4.0 the call to `ToArray` will be [obviated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(VS.100).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
public static string DictToQueryString(Dictionary<string, string> data)
{
    StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder();

    foreach(var pair in data)
    {
        if (queryString.Length > 0)
            queryString.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
        else
            queryString.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }

    return queryString.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Also, the type for "pair" will be KeyValuePair<string, string>.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for?

```
public static string DictToQueryString(Dictionary<string, string> data)
{
    string querystring = "";

    foreach (string key in data.Keys)
    {
        string val = data[key];
        querystring += key + "=" + val + "&";
    }

    return querystring;
}
```